# how to draw a truth table for following logical expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra

It's a question in my assignment, which I don't really understand it. However, there is an example here.

**e.g. A computer uses the following logical expression to control a finger print scanner.**

> F(A, B, C, D) = Σ (0, 1, 4, 5, 12, 14)

What will be the truth table of the function F?

The solution looks like this:
[image]

Can anyone explain how the truth table can be drawn from the function F? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your notation? It's not clear what this means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is under sigma notation is '1's and everything else is '0's
[image]

so take this table as the format and fill up it using '1's and '0's according to the sigma notation you got :) and simplifiy is using K-maps

Comment: Oh I get it now! Thanks a lot :)